# Silence loggers and printing to screen - Python

Tags: python, logging, printing, mechanize

I'm having a problem with my python script.

It's printing massive amounts of data on the screen, and I would like to prevent all sorts of printing to screen.

---

**Edit:**

The library I'm using is **mechanize**, and it's printing a LOT of data on screen.

I have set these to false with no luck!

```
br.set_debug_redirects(False)
br.set_debug_responses(False)
br.set_debug_http(False)
```

---

Any ideas?

Help would be amazing and very much appreciated!

Comment: Can you give some more information? What script are you talking about? What kind of data is it printing? Can you show some code? Are you using external scripts?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

(Based on your 2nd edit)

If you don't want to disable all output, you can try to be specific to `mechanize` itself. http://wwwsearch.sourceforge.net/mechanize/ provides a snippet, which I've modified (though I'm not sure if it will work):

```
import logging
logger = logging.getLogger("mechanize")
# only log really bad events
logger.setLevel(logging.ERROR)
```

---

When you print something it goes to the screen through the `sys.stdout` file. You can change this file to any other file (eg, a log file you open) so that nothing is printed to the screen:

```
import sys
# save the old stdout so you can print later (do sys.stdout = OLD_STDOUT)
OLD_STDOUT = sys.stdout
sys.stdout = open("logfile.txt", 'w')
```

Of course, if you're talking about some library that you're calling, it may be printing to `sys.stderr`. Luckily, you can do the exact same thing for this one (continuing from above):

```
OLD_STDERR = sys.stderr
sys.stderr = open("errorLog.txt", 'w')
```

Now if, for some reason, you want to completely ignore stdout (or stderr) and never see it again, you can define your own file-like classes that simply discard the objects:

```
class Discarder(object):
    def write(self, text):
        pass # do nothing
# now discard everything coming out of stdout
sys.stdout = Discarder()
```

And, to add to the din of possible solutions, here is a solution that works in Unix shells:

```
# discards all input (change /dev/null to a file name to keep track of output)
python yourScript.py > /dev/null
```

Comment: Thanks for the AMAZING reply! sorry about the True/False typo

Comment: AttributeError: 'Discarder' object has no attribute 'flush'

Answer (score 2):

You may redirect sys.stdout and sys.stderr to a file or any file like object of yours e.g.

```
class EatLog(object):
    def write(self):
       pass

sys.stdout = EatLog()
```

but i would not recommend that, simpler option is to use OS level redirection e.g.

```
python myscript.py > out.log
```

Comment: and if you need to redirect stderr too (in bash) `python myscript.py 2>&1 > out.log`

Answer (score 0):

you can use the `StringIO` module, too, instead of rolling your own stdout stream.  Occasionally, the stdout needs more than a `write` method (`flush` is another common one), which StringIO will handle.

```
import StringIO
import sys

sys.stdout = StringIO.StringIO()
```